# Mathematica convex optimization

Tags: optimization, wolfram-mathematica, convex

I am trying to solve some problems that can be mapped in convex optimisation problem.
In particular is for analysis of quantum state tomography data.

In Matlab there are some tools to help you do this, like SeDuMi or CVX

http://sedumi.ie.lehigh.edu
http://cvxr.com/cvx/

But I could not find anything similar in Mathematica, on the web or in the forums.

Does anybody know if there is an easy way of implementing this kind of algorithm in Mathematica?

I would like to avoid to be forced to switch to Matlab to solve this problem. Nothing against it, but I have most of the programming for this state tomography developed in Mathematica.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution in Mathematica?

Answer (score 0):

I had also some troubles with Mathematica in
optimization, exactly on convex problems.

I suggest you export to CVX, which will require
some work because it wants the problem in matrix notation.

Otherwise, to remain with the algebraic formulation, 
you could try with Maple, which has, as far
as I can tell, better optimizers than Mathematica.
([check the doc](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Optimization/Minimize) to have an idea)